# How to add auto codecomplete for .net dll in pycharm or any other IDE

Tags: python, .net, import, autocomplete, python.net

I have a .net dll imported into python 2.7.9

```
import sys
import clr
import System
from System.Reflection import Assembly
Engine = Assembly.LoadFile(r'file.dll')
```

Now what i need is a codecomplete  for that .net dll.
After import when using the python command line i can use the dir() to see the method inside the classes.

But as for now i'm using the pycharm community 4.0.6 and i can't understand how to add the .net dll to be used for auto codecomplete.

Also i think that maybe i can strip the API of the .net dll and add it as reference but i don't know which tool can help me here

P.S- 
if this is not supported in pycharm and supported by other IDE please advise

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jupyter/IPython and PTVS REPL for Python.NET tab completion. Static analysis cannot get these live objects.

Answer (score 0):

This forum post I found doesn't state explicitly, but they suggest to just select to ignore the import if it complains.

http://fougerite.com/threads/setup-pycharm-for-python-plugins.198/

I would prefer an answer to come along that indicates that this is possible, but wouldn't be surprised to learn that such is not possible at the moment. Feature request for PyCharm?